# java typing into file, file not showing, using bytes

Tags: java, byte, fileoutputstream

i need some help here.
I changed a int to an hex after that changing it to byte and tried writing it into a file.
But the file does not appear in the directory as the jar file i build.

```
 File ModFile =new File(NameText.getText() + ".mod");
FileOutputStream writer = null;

String toProcess = CodesBox.getText();
int i = Integer.parseInt(CodesBox.getText());
byte codes = (byte) i;  

try {
    writer = new FileOutputStream(ModFile);
    writer.write(codes);

} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(ModMakerGui.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}finally{
    try {
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

NameText.getText() is definitely there
and the CodesBox.getText() is also definitely correct.

[image: see this image]
As you can see this is what i get when i open the generated file in an hex editor.
But i would want this instead.
[image: IMG]
May i know how to fix this?
I know the output file is "vPTP       " with spaces, i need the spaces, thank you

Comment: Where are you changing anything into hex? I only see `parseInt`, which changes text into binary.

Comment: "file not showing", does that mean that the file does not contain what you expected or that you can not find the file at all? Do you get any other errors (from Integer.parseInt perhaps)?

Comment: no, the file does not appear in the directory as the program

Comment: i updated the main post to make it clearer, pls help

Comment: I updated it again, please help someone

Answer (score 0):

Please use either `FileWriter` or `PrintWriter`.

For example:

```
modFile = new File(NameText.getText() + ".mod");
FileWriter writer = null;
if(!modFile.exists()){
   try {
      modFile.createNewFile();
      writer = new FileWriter(ModFile);
      System.out.println("Mod file has been created to the current directory");
      writer.write(CodesBox.getText());
   } catch (IOException ex) {
      Logger.getLogger(ModMakerGui.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
   }
}
```

Comment: i want to write them in bytes though

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you use **FileOutputStream** as well as to write bytes.

```
File ModFile =new File(NameText.getText() + ".mod");
FileOutputStream writer = null;

try {
    writer = new FileOutputStream(ModFile);
    writer.write(CodesBox.getText().getBytes(),0,CodesBox.getText().getBytes().length);

} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(ModMakerGui.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}finally{
    try {
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, it still does not solve my problem. I am changing my main post to make it clearer